# Thread execution sequence on synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading

In below code I'm trying to figure out threads handle execution on synchronized blocks:

```
public class ThreadExp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r, "Thread1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r, "Thread2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        callFn();
    }

    private void callFn() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": entered callSync()");
        synchronized (Thread.currentThread()) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": inside sync");
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " leaving sync");
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": leaving callSync()");
    }
}
```

**Actual Output:**

```
    Thread1: entered callFn()
    Thread2: entered callFn()
    Thread1: inside sync block
    Thread2: inside sync block
// 5000 millisec sleep
    Thread2 leaving sync block
    Thread1 leaving sync block
    Thread2: leaving callFn()
    Thread1: leaving callFn()
```

**Whereas I expected something like:**

```
Thread1: entered callFn()
Thread2: entered callFn()
Thread1: inside sync block
// 5000 millisec sleep
Thread1 leaving sync block
Thread1: leaving callFn()
Thread2: inside sync block
Thread2 leaving sync block
Thread2: leaving callFn()
```

Overall I thought Thread1 will acquire the lock then go to sleep. And only after Thread1 is finished, Thread2 can enter the synchronized block.

Comment: Synchronizing on the current thread object will *never* block. How could it? Contention occurs when multiple threads try to enter a lock, but in your case each thread is entering a unique lock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are synchronizing on the thread itself:

```
synchronized (Thread.currentThread())
```

so each thread has its own lock and they can execute the `synchronized` block concurrently.

If you want the `synchronized` block to be run by only one thread at a time, you need to use the same lock.

In your example, it could simply be `this`, since the `Runnable` instance is the same for your two threads:

```
synchronized(this) {...}
```

The output will then look like:

```
Thread1: entered callSync()
Thread1: inside sync
Thread2: entered callSync()
Thread1 leaving sync
Thread1: leaving callSync()
Thread2: inside sync
Thread2 leaving sync
Thread2: leaving callSync()
```

Comment: Synchronizing on Thread.currentThread() seems completely useless - frankly, seems like a bug.  Is there a case where that is ever useful?

Comment: @user949300 What it does is it creates a memory barrier but there are much better ways to achieve the same.